# $R$ is an integral domain but not a field. Prove $R[x]$ is not a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My problem is "$R$ is an integral domain but not a field. Prove $R[x]$ is not a Dedekind domain".

The reason I find this problem difficult is that I don't know any effective methods to prove an integral domain is NOT a Dedekind domain. So please tell me some ways to approach this kind of problems. Thank you

Comment: To check not every prime ideal is maximal may be the simplest way to go in some cases. For example, $\;\langle x\rangle\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ . Try to mimic this for a general integral domain, say $\;\langle x\rangle\,\lneq \langle x,\,r\rangle\;$ with $\;r\in\Bbb R\;$ non-invertible and non-zero.

Comment: Hint: One of the properties one shows Dedekind domains to have is that the quotient by any non-zero prime ideal is a field.

Comment: So $xR[x]$ is a prime ideal but $xR[x]+a R[x]$ is a larger ideal not being the whole ring if $a$ is not a unit in $R$. How do you show it implies $R[x]$ not being a Dedekind domain ?

Comment: Probably easier: $R[x]/(x)\cong R$.

Comment: Thank you for all of your precious hints and answers. Now I can solve my problem. You make it a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dedekind ring can be characterized as a Noetherian, integrally closed ring of Krull dimension $1$. Now $A=R[x]$ has Krull dimension $\dim R[x]=\dim R+1$. Now an integral domain $R$ has Krull dimension zero, if and only if it is a field.
Hence $R$ is a field.